# thread error in flask app using python and scrapy

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, scrapy, twisted

I dont want this to be a "find the error for me" post, however, I do not have knowledge about how threading works or how the Twisted module works.

That being said, I am getting this error when trying to run a scraper

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

I have tried and failed to figure out what exactly this means exactly but have not succeeded. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Here is the main script:

```
# [START app]
import logging
import subprocess
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template
import send_email_lemay
#import send_email_cave
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/lemay', methods=['POST'])
def view_do_something():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        send_email_lemay.main("djgraff1@cougars.ccis.edu")
        #your database process here
        #subprocess.call(['python2.7', 'send_email_lemay.py'])
        #time.sleep(400)
        return "OK"

    else:
        return "NO OK"

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    # Log the error and stacktrace.
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return 'An internal error occurred.', 500
# [END app]


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082, debug=True)
```

And then here is the script that actually does the scraping:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import smtplib,ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders
import datetime
import time
import os
from competition.spiders.AStorageInnLemay import AStorageInnLemay
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


def sendmail(email):
    spider = AStorageInnLemay()
    crawler = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()
    log.start()
    reactor.run() # the script will block here

    filez = "blah.csv" #%(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H"))

    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(open(filez, "rb").read())

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = "djgraff1@cougars.ccis.edu"
    msg['To'] = email #"astoraginnlemay@gmail.com"
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime = True)
    msg['Subject'] = "Competition Report"
    msg.attach(MIMEText("Lemay"))

    content = 'example email stuff here'    
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)    
    mail.ehlo()    
    mail.starttls()    
    mail.login('djgraff1@cougars.ccis.edu','2ZNf+Uy}')    
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="data on Lemay %s.csv"'%(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%s-%m-%d-%y")))
    msg.attach(part)

    try:
        mail.sendmail('djgraff1@cougars.ccis.edu',email,msg.as_string())
        print 'email sentasfd'
    except:
        print 'email not sent'
    os.remove(filez)

def sleep():
    time.sleep(4000)

def monitor(email):
    sendmail(email)

def main(email):
    monitor(email)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(email)
```

When i run my app and click the button to run the scraper I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1203, in _handleSignals
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sigInt)
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Comment: The posted code isn't runnable.  There are missing external dependencies and internal bugs (eg `email` is undefined at the end of the scraper).  Perhaps there is also some kind of missing scrapy configuration?  This makes it hard to run the code and so hard to reproduce the failure and so hard to debug.  It would be particularly interesting to be able to see the complete traceback you're encountering but this is not possible without runnable code.

Comment: Thank you jean-paul i have since moved on from this project. If i pick it back up soon i will include the stacktrace